# Align text with a value

Tags: css

Text can be centered in a div with `text-align: center;`

But what if I want it to be 50px from the left? Is there an alternative to setting a padding to the parent div like `padding-left: 50px;`?

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying. So you want the text to be just off-center by 50px?

Comment: You could use `margin-left: 50px;` on the child element.

Comment: off-left, not off-center.

Comment: So not at all centered at all then? Just a margin/padding of 50px from the left? If so what is the problem with what you are using?

Comment: `padding-left` will work just fine for this.

Comment: Just to be different, you could always use `border-left:50px solid #FFF;` (if your background is white)

Comment: I want to align some text from the margin with a precise value in px. 'center' doesn't help me, since it's not a certain px value.

Comment: That border-left idea is actually pretty good, too.

Comment: Did @zessx solution work for you? If not, please try to explain better as to what exactly you want.

Comment: Shall I make it an answer?  I really need 10 points!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to be different, you could always use `border-left:50px solid #FFF;` (if your background is white)

In response to comment - let's make it transparent, why not:

```
border-left:50px solid transparent;
```

Someone, please tell IE6 what this means.

Comment: Nice one. Change it for `transparent` for the best !

Answer (score 3):

If it's a one-line text, `text-indent` is here !

```
div.left-aligned {
    width: 300px;
    text-indent: 50px;
}
```

For a multiline text, `padding-left` is your man. I suggest you to use it with `box-sizing: border-box` to avoid extra size for your container :

```
div.left-aligned {
    width: 300px;
    padding-left: 50px;
    box-sizing: border-box; /* make the box 300px large, not 350px */
}
```

Comment: All the text, not only the first line.